# opencv screen recording returning video file with only 6KB

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the below python code to record windows screen in one of my frameworks. But opencv captures a video file of size only 6KB.

I have tried all workarounds as suggested in stackoverflow for earlier similar issue but to no avail. 
1)I have renamed the ffmpeg dll.
2)I have copied under python directory
3)I have also added the path of variable to environment variables
4)Changed height and width.

```
import time, threading, numpy as np, cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab

def startThread(running):
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')
    vid = cv2.VideoWriter('record.avi', fourcc, 30, (960, 720))
    while running.is_set():
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img_np = np.array(img)
        vid.write(img_np)

def stopThread():
    time.sleep(10)
    running.clear()

def startVideoThread():
    running.set()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=startThread, args=(running,))
    thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    running = threading.Event()
    startVideoThread()
    stopThread()
```

All these have not resulted in solving my issue.
The one thing driving me crazy is the same code works on my colleagues laptop with the same configurations as mine. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What system are you using? Have you tried this example? https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/VideoReadWriteDisplay/videoWrite.py

Answer (score -1):

Your `ImageGrab.grab()` has size, but it must be the `VideoWriter` size.